# How to open full version of the site that was built on Django?

Tags: html, django, web

I have my first website that is based on Django 3. It’s good when I open it using my PC, but when I use mobile phone, it opens as a mobile version and compresses all the visual content so it looks awful. How can I make it open as a full version?

Comment: Many browsers on mobile allow you to view the website as a desktop version. Try finding this button? Which app are you using?

Comment: There is no such a button, because I didn’t make it for my website (any browser). Anyway I would like it to open the full version every time

Comment: Your website doesn't need to have the button. The browser comes installed with the button.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem with django specifically. When you create a website, you are using HTML to tell the browser where to find the content that you need. Here's an example:

```
<p> Some text here... </p>
<img src="someimage.jpg">
```

As you can see, we have some text and an image. We told our browser what the **content** of our website is.

With CSS (Cascading Style Sheet) we **style** our **content**. This means that we're telling the browser how the HTML should *look* like. For that we use **rules**. Here's an example:

**HTML:**

```
<p class="text"> Some text here... </p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.text{
   font-size:12px,
}
```

We set a **rule** that tells the browser the following: "Every element that has the `class` attribute named `text` should have a font size of 12 pixels.

Like we did this, we can also set a **rule** for only mobile devices. It should say the following thing: "If the width of the current screen is less than 920 pixels (mobile width), paint the paragraphs in red". That translated is this:

```
@media (max-width: 920px) {
  p{
     color: red;
  }
}
```

Those are called media queries. Of course, there are many ways to make your content adaptable to smaller screens, like flexbox. If you're using bootstrap, check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) link out.

Answer (score -1):

This responsive behavior is managed by media queries inside your css files (static files)
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

We need to see some code to help.

if only need to view your site as you were on a desktop, mobile browsers generally have a "view as desktop" feature

Comment: I can give a link to my repo https://github.com/rukavishnikovmihail00/WeatherApp

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no css files. The only css I use here is a link to Bootstrap

Comment: You will need to override bootstrap, take a look at : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/#disable-responsive  => https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css